# Ansible write result command to local file with loop

Tags: ansible

I've write ansible-playbook to collect the result from many network devices. Below playbook is working fine. But if I have to collect result with lot of commands. Let say 20 commands, I've to create the many task to write the results into file in my playbook.

For now, I manually create the tasks to write to logs into file. Below is example with 3 commands.

```
- name: run multiple commands and evaluate the output
  hosts: <<network-host>>
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars:
    datetime: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H') }}"
    backup_dir: "/backup/"

  cli:
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    username: <<username>>
    password: <<password>>

  tasks:
  - sros_command:
     commands:
       - show version
       - show system information
       - show port
     provider: "{{ cli }}"
  register: result

- name: Writing output
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ datetime }}.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:# show version\n{{ result.stdout[0] }}"
    create: yes
  changed_when: False

- name: Writing output
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ datetime }}.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:# show system information\n{{ result.stdout[1] }}"
    create: yes
  changed_when: False

- name: Writing output
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ datetime }}.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:# show port\n{{ cmd_result.stdout[2] }}"
    create: yes
  changed_when: False
```

Is it possible to loop commands and result within one task?

Please kindly advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this one task alone in place above three tasks..

```
- name: Writing output
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ datetime }}.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:# show {{ item.command }}\n{{ cmd_result.stdout{{ item.outnum }} }}"
    create: yes
  changed_when: False
  with_items:
      - { command: version, outnum: [0] }
      - { command: system information, outnum: [1] }
      - { command: port, outnum: [2] }
```

Comment: Hi Appu, thank you for your help

I got error 

"fatal: [Network1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'. String: {{ inventory_hostname }}:# show {{ item.command }}\n{{ cmd_result.stdout{{ item.outnum }} }}"}"

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below playbook is worked for me

```
- name: Writing output
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ datetime }}.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:# show {{ item.command }}\n{{ item.cmdoutput}}"
    create: yes
  changed_when: False
  with_items:
    - { command: "version", cmdoutput: "{{ cmd_result.stdout[0] }}" }
    - { command: "system information", cmdoutput: "{{ cmd_result.stdout[1] }}" }
    - { command: "port", cmdoutput: "{{ cmd_result.stdout[2] }}" }
```